# onSubmit method of SimpleFormController does not submit for edit form

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am implementing a simple Guestbook in Spring which allows me to delete and edit posts. I am using the same Form-View for both creating and editing a post. When I edit posts the form is prefilled with the data from the `GuestbookEntry` Object. For creating a new post the whole process works fine, but for the editing part clicking on the Submit button (which triggers `onSubmit()`) in my `SimpleFormController` does not redirect to the view I specified.

This means that there a basically two different responses I get for the same form, using the same `onSubmit()` method.

1. When creating a new post I click on Submit and I am being redirected to my `guestbook.jsp` View
2. When editing a post I clock on Submit and nothing happens (there are also no exceptions being thrown)

Here is the code of my `onSubmit()` method

```java
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command) throws ServletException {
        Guestbook guestbook = (Guestbook) command;
        guestbook.setTimestamp(new Date());
        GuestbookHandler gbHandler = GuestbookHandler.getInstance();
        if(guestbook.getEntryId() != 0) {
            gbHandler.editGuestbookEntry(guestbook.getEntryId(), guestbook);
        } else {
            gbHandler.addGuestbookEntry(guestbook);
        }
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("guestbook", "guestbookEntries", gbHandler.getGuestbookEntries());
        modelAndView.setViewName("guestbook");
        return modelAndView;
        
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you are editing a post and click on submit, do you know if the request reaches your Spring app? In other words, are you positive that the browser is actually submitting something to the server?

Comment: I can see the POST request on the browser console. It has status 200 (OK).

Comment: And where is your browser redirected to once you hit submit, while editing a post?

Comment: Okay I think we're getting close. So when I edit a post, the URL is editEntry.app while when creating a new post the URL is createEditEntry.app which corresponds with an existing .jsp (createEditEntry.jsp). The is already a requestMapping for editEntry which brings you back to the form. I am guessing the URL is causing that problem, always calling the same "show me the form" method i created.

Comment: Yes, looks like the url used once you post an edit is going to the wrong URL... make sure whatever URL is mapped to your method `onSubmit` is invoked once you post the form on a submit